# script in PHP to check whether the server is alive or not

Tags: php, ajax, testing

I am internee at software testing and given the task to write a script in PHP which will be placed on the server and it will check after every 10 mins that whether the server is alive or not.

**solution # 1:**
The solutions that came up in my mind is to write a simple ajax function to connect with the server if the connection is established un-successfully then generate a mail through another function that server is down! but this solution got rejected by one of my senior dev.

**Solution # 2:**
write a simple query to fetch any info from the server if the result found then it means server is alive else send the error!
place this script to the server and assign cron-job to run this test timely!
for this solution one of my dev team said *the first step is to get the connection established fetching data comes next* so i guess this solution failed too :(

now i need to connect to the server using php and do the same task for this i have looked up and found different solutions. `http://snipplr.com/view/33950`, 
 `http://www.thecave.info/php-ping-script-to-check-remote-server-or-website/` these two are quite understandable as i'm a new-bee, but when i tried to copy and run the same task then both are not working for me! the first link is not giving any output while the second one is always giving the "server is down" message.

I've tried playing around with different articles to do this but have come away with nothing so far! if the solutions are provided with elaborated examples it would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Simply write a script to query your index and use a `cron job` to run the script every `x` many minutes.

Comment: If you are a internee and a new dev and have been given a task that you either do not understand or need guidance on, ask your supervisor / mentor for assistance or a direction to follow. It would be better to understand the task and related steps to achieve success than to simply copy another dev's code and massage it to fit your requirement. An internee should be guided and taught - not thrown in at the deep end with no assistance

Comment: @ObsidianAge that's one of the solution i got but the main issue i'm having is how to connect with the server through php, as i only know is how to connect with the sql server.

Comment: That's OK; we're more than happy to help with that :) Though StackOverflow does expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @gavgrif i understand that process but i have not been provided with any supervisor that's why i decided to ask for help!  plus i'm only using these links to understand the task deeply i have to modify these according to my requirements on my own.

Comment: Hopefully you're an intern and not an internee, the latter meaning a prisoner.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks for the guidelines. the question has been updated!